# Stream data is lost when declaring new TextFieldParser()

Tags: c#, .net

I am passing a Stream from a csv file from my Controller to my business layer for processing. The stream makes it to the method okay but as soon as I declare my TextFieldParser, and pass in my stream, the data is gone and is therefore not processed.

```
    public CsvRecordReportModel processCsvStream(Stream dataStream, RecordSource recordSource, string fileName)
    {
        //Create instance of the report. 
        var report = new CsvRecordReportModel();
        report.InsertedRecordCount = 0;
        report.FileName = fileName;

        using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(dataStream))
        {
            csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] {"#"};
            csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] {","});
            csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            // Skip the row with the column names
            csvParser.ReadLine();

            while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
            {
               //Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could be that the dataStream object is at the end of the Stream. Maybe use dataStream.Seek(0,0); to set it to the start.

Comment: What does `the data is gone and is therefore not processed.` mean? `ReadLine` fails? Something else? Is the stream open in the first place? Does it contain the delimiters you think it does, including line endings? Where do you call `ReadFields()` ?

Comment: How do you know `the data is gone`?

Comment: BTW you should explain what [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) is, including a link. It's *not* widely used. For example, it requires `\r\n` as the line delimiter. It's quite possible that the data uses `\n` so `ReadLine()` skips the *entire* file. It doesn't scale to large files either. You should probably use a *different* class like CsvHelper

Comment: Ugh. I didn't reset it to 0,0 and it was past the end of the stream from the start. Thank you Ross Miller for pointing that out. This can be closed or deleted.